# How to unsubscribe a websocket topic before an async/await?

Tags: angular, websocket

A `.on()` function was created to connect to the topic, and an `.off()` function to disconnect from the topic.

The `.on()` function is an `async/await` and returns me a subject.

The subject is actually the communication with the websocket.

I need to give `.off()` which is the unsubscribe from the topic, in another function at another time, but that doesn't work.

It only works if I do `.off()` after `.on()`.

```
// DONT WORK
this.websocketTopicTest.off('FOO');
await this.websocketTopicTest.on('FOO');


// WORK
await this.websocketTopicTest.on('FOO');
this.websocketTopicTest.off('FOO');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using websocket wrapper from `rxjs` https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket#examples

```js
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

const subject = webSocket('ws://localhost:8081');

const observableA = subject.multiplex(
  () => ({ subscribe: 'A' }), // When server gets this message, it will start sending messages for 'A'...
  () => ({ unsubscribe: 'A' }), // ...and when gets this one, it will stop.
  message => message.type === 'A' // If the function returns `true` message is passed down the stream. Skipped if the function returns false.
);

const observableB = subject.multiplex( // And the same goes for 'B'.
  () => ({ subscribe: 'B' }),
  () => ({ unsubscribe: 'B' }),
  message => message.type === 'B'
);

const subA = observableA.subscribe(messageForA => console.log(messageForA));
// At this moment WebSocket connection is established. Server gets '{"subscribe": "A"}' message and starts sending messages for 'A',
// which we log here.

const subB = observableB.subscribe(messageForB => console.log(messageForB));
// Since we already have a connection, we just send '{"subscribe": "B"}' message to the server. It starts sending messages for 'B',
// which we log here.

subB.unsubscribe();
// Message '{"unsubscribe": "B"}' is sent to the server, which stops sending 'B' messages.

subA.unsubscribe();
// Message '{"unsubscribe": "A"}' makes the server stop sending messages for 'A'. Since there is no more subscribers to root Subject,
// socket connection closes.
```

`off` analogue should be properly implemented and run when we unsubscribe subscription